# How to use the upload and screenshot controls？

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core mvc project, and I need a function request, the function of uploading pictures and allowing users to take screenshots at will, I goole a lot, I currently find a screenshot of a form, is there any upload function in the view?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y), new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Width, this.Height));
            IntPtr t1= g.GetHdc();
            g.ReleaseHdc(t1);
            myImage.Save(@"c:\screen1.jpg");
}
```

Comment: It makes little sense to include a WinForms code sample when asking for a solution that works in ASP.NET Core MVC, there is nothing in common between the two as far as UI handling is concerned. You'd have to look at browser-based solutions, a browser is where MVC output is rendered and where the screenshot will have to be taken. See e.g. https://hackernoon.com/how-to-take-screenshots-in-the-browser-using-javascript-l92k3xq7. Then you'd still have decide how to transfer the screenshot back from the browser to MVC on the server, assuming that is where you want it to be processed or stored.

Comment: What do you mean by the code you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to upload pictures and then take screenshots, and then upload the screenshots to the backend, you can refer to this demo, which may be helpful to you.

First create an Images folder under your `wwwroot`.

Controller code:

```
  public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment Environment;

        public ImageController(IHostingEnvironment _environment)
        {
            Environment = _environment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Save()
        {
            string base64 = Request.Form["imgCropped"];
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64.Split(',')[1]);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "Images", "Test.png");
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                stream.Flush();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

View code:

```
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Image" asp-action="Save">
        <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img id="Image1" src="" alt="" style="display: none" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <canvas id="canvas" height="5" width="5"></canvas>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnCrop" value="Crop" style="display: none" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" style="display: none" />
        <input type="hidden" name="imgX1" id="imgX1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="imgY1" id="imgY1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="imgWidth" id="imgWidth" />
        <input type="hidden" name="imgHeight" id="imgHeight" />
        <input type="hidden" name="imgCropped" id="imgCropped" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.9/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#FileUpload1').change(function () {
                $('#Image1').hide();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#Image1').show();
                    $('#Image1').attr("src", e.target.result);
                    $('#Image1').Jcrop({
                        onChange: SetCoordinates,
                        onSelect: SetCoordinates
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
            });

            $('#btnCrop').click(function () {
                var x1 = $('#imgX1').val();
                var y1 = $('#imgY1').val();
                var width = $('#imgWidth').val();
                var height = $('#imgHeight').val();
                var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    canvas.height = height;
                    canvas.width = width;
                    context.drawImage(img, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                    $('#imgCropped').val(canvas.toDataURL());
                    $('#btnUpload').show();
                };
                img.src = $('#Image1').attr("src");
            });
        });
        function SetCoordinates(c) {
            $('#imgX1').val(c.x);
            $('#imgY1').val(c.y);
            $('#imgWidth').val(c.w);
            $('#imgHeight').val(c.h);
            $('#btnCrop').show();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

You can also use the Croppie plugin, read this documentation:

https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

Comment: It works, thanks. I wanted to find an easier way, but thanks for your time anyway.